# Could not load AJAX TOOLKIT or dependencies, access denied After get latest from tfs

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, permissions, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Here's the situation.  I built a small internal app using vs 2012, .net framework 4.5, asp and vb.net.  Got everything working, deployed it successfully.  It ran just fine when I ran it in debug, and it runs just fine on the app server.  Due to some file-mismanagement, I lost my development version on my machine, and was forced to re-download everything from our source control.  I'm pretty sure all my latest changes were checked in.

So the problem is now that once I got the code back on my machine, I started getting the blue squiggle of death under the first line on every aspx page, and the error "Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied"  I've dealt with this before, when first setting up the machine, adding rights for network service and or IIS_IUsers to the temp asp folder under users, but those rights are already there.  None of my other projects seem to be having any trouble.  I've tried deleting the contents of the temp asp folder, nothing changes.  Tried deleting and re-adding the file itself and the reference in the project.  Tried moving the location of the actual ajaxToolKit.dll file, tried just in the bin folder, tried one directory up with the .vb and .aspx folders... I've looked at what I could find online, and every "solution" is just to clear the temp asp folder, or make sure IIS_Iusers has full control on that folder... I saw some stuff about messing with the web.config file, but that was for older versions of asp and older websites that previously didn't have ajax... this one has it, and it runs fine, except on my machine.  When my coworker tried to download a copy of the project from source control, she got the same issue.

Does anyone have any idea what could have changed, and how to change it back? It's pretty clear this is a permissions issue, with the "access is denied" statement, but I'm pretty sure I've got all the rights accounted for.

HELP!

Additionally, here is the error screen when I try to run in debug now... not sure if there's anything here I'm missing...

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = Unknown
LOG: DisplayName = AjaxControlToolkit
Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: AjaxControlToolkit | Domain ID: 2
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Projects/RegZNotes/NotesProject/NotesProject/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Projects\RegZNotes\NotesProject\NotesProject\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file:    C:\Projects\RegZNotes\NotesProject\NotesProject\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\jhubbard.WSB\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/a8da425c/cc9043b6/AjaxControlToolkit.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/a8da425c/cc9043b6/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxControlToolkit.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Projects/RegZNotes/NotesProject/NotesProject/bin/AjaxControlToolkit.DLL.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Projects\RegZNotes\NotesProject\NotesProject\web.config
```

LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\jhubbard.WSB\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
   LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
   LOG: Post-policy reference: AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.50508.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e
   ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80070005). Probing terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem; our DBA actually figured it out:

When an App uses impersonation, that "user" needs rights on all the folders... so while I had granted IIS_IUsers full control of those folders, it didn't matter, until I added the impersonated user to that group on my machine.